# Call custom function with if statement in the summarize function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to call a custom function to do some calculation. In this function, there is one if statement to check the input values. But my codes don't return values I expected.

Created a test data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
df <- expand.grid(x = 2:4, y = 2:4, z = 2:4)
df$value <- df$x
df <- df%>% tbl_df %>% group_by(x, y)
```

test_fun1 just return sum of all values

```
test_fun1 <- function(value)
{
    return(sum(value))
}
df %>% summarize(t  = test_fun1(value))
```

test_fun1 return results as my expected

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: x

  x y t
1 1 1 2
2 1 2 2
3 2 1 4
4 2 2 4
```

Then I add a if statement to check whether all values equal.

```
test_fun2 <- function(value)
{
    if (all(value == 2))
    {
        return (NA)
    }
    return(sum(value))
}
df  %>% summarize(t  = test_fun2(value))
```

But test_fun2 return TRUE for values are more than 2

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: x

  x y    t
1 2 2   NA
2 2 3   NA
3 2 4   NA
4 3 2 TRUE
5 3 3 TRUE
6 3 4 TRUE
7 4 2 TRUE
8 4 3 TRUE
9 4 4 TRUE
```

Results are as expected for other values for test_fun3 for other values.

```
test_fun3 <- function(value)
{
    if (all(value != 3))
    {
        return(sum(value))
    }
    return (NA)

}
df  %>% summarize(t  = test_fun3(value))
```

I could get the similar results for 4 or 5

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: x

  x y  t
1 2 2  6
2 2 3  6
3 2 4  6
4 3 2 NA
5 3 3 NA
6 3 4 NA
7 4 2 12
8 4 3 12
9 4 4 12
```

In my real data, I got FALSE of non NA testing, but can not create a reproduce example here.

Any ideas about this problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1.0.99 magrittr_1.0.1      parallel_3.1.0     
[4] Rcpp_0.11.1         tools_3.1.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is obviously, that `mutate` tries to determine the class of the column from the first assignment and applies this class to all other groups. And the class of `NA` is (in your case unfortunately) `logical`. For more details you can have a look here https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/299

I would suggest, that you work around this by assigning a casted `NA`. See also `? NA`

```
test_fun2 <- function(value) {
  if (all(value == 2)) {
    return (NA_integer_)
  }
  return(sum(value))
}

df  %>% summarize(t  = test_fun2(value))

Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: x

  x y  t
1 2 2 NA
2 2 3 NA
3 2 4 NA
4 3 2  9
5 3 3  9
6 3 4  9
7 4 2 12
8 4 3 12
9 4 4 12
```